# Matlab: Error using ==> mpower

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use `fsolve` in matlab to solve a system of nonlinear equations numerically. Here is a test sample of my program, `k1` and `R` are parameters and `x0` is the start point.

```
function y=f(k1, R, x0)

pair=fsolve(@system,x0);

y=pair(1);

    function r=system(v)

        int1=@(x) exp(k1*x);
        int2=@(x) exp(k1*x^2)/(x^4);


        r(1)=exp(v(1))*quadl(int1,0,v(1));     
        r(2)=exp(k1*v(2))*quadl(int2,v(1),20)*k1*R;

    end

end
```

The strange thing is when I run this program, matlab keeps telling me that I should use `.^` instead of `^` in `int2=@(x) exp(k1*x^2)/(x^4)`. I am confused because the `x` in that function handle is supposed to be a scalar when it is used by `quadl`. Why should I have to use `.^` in this case?

Also I see that a lot of the examples provided in online documentations also use `.^` even though they are clearly taking power of a scalar, as in [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadl.html). Can anybody help explain why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the function `int2` you have used matrix power (`^`) where you should use element-wise power (`.^`). Also, you have used matrix right division (`/`) where you should use element-wise division (`./`). This is needed, since `quadl` (and friends) will evaluate the integrand `int2` for a whole array of `x`'s at a time for reasons of efficiency.

So, use this:

```
function y = f(k1, R, x0)

    pair = fsolve(@system,x0);

    y = pair(1);

    function r = system(v)

        int1 = @(x) exp(k1*x);
        int2 = @(x) exp(k1*x.^2)./(x.^4);

        r(1) = exp(   v(1)) * quadl(int1,0,v(1));     
        r(2) = exp(k1*v(2)) * k1*R*quadl(int2,v(1),20);

    end

end
```

Also, have a look at `quadgk` or `integral` (if you're on newer Matlab).

By the way, I assume your real functions `int1` and `int2` are different functions? Because these functions are of course [trivial](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=Exp%5bk1%2ax%5d%2F+x%2a%2a4&random=false) to solve analytically...

Comment: Thank you very much Rody! Yeah the real ones are different (in fact they do not even have a closerd form). But I'm getting errors in them and I'm new to matlab, so I try to decompose it into test samples and see where the bug is :)

Comment: @Vokram: Elliptic integrals and Bessel functions etc. are not closed-form either, but can be evaluated much faster than a quadrature method. Have you tried them in the online Mathematica integrator?

Comment: Thanks Rody. Apologies for my limited knowledge in mathematics... The function I am trying to evaluate is an integral of an integral (from an economic model I'm building), so my current plan is to use multiple function handles in `fslove`. Not sure if this fits in with your method?

Comment: @Vokram: Can you edit your question and show me what the functions are? Or perhaps, a link to a page where they can be found? It would greatly benefit your program's speed if there was an analytic solution...

Comment: Sure, I would very much appreciate your opinion :) Please see this dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf2uf9hs1y9zj3d/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-24%20at%2011.03.49%20PM.png I'm trying to solve the pair (S,$\lambda$0).

Comment: It is very messy, and based on my trials so far the existence of the solution seems to depend on the parameters, which I still need to run some more regressions to figure out... Sorry if this looks crazy...

Comment: Sorry Rody, forgot to include that. m(x) is a survival function: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4t8xzddzglovig/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-25%20at%2010.55.46%20AM.png

Comment: @Vokram: Well now, that makes analytic solutions possible! For the first integral, [click here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral[+Exp[+%28%281-n1%29%2F%281-n2%29%29*d*x+%2B+n2%2F%281-n2%29*r*x]+%2F+%28+%28264-Exp[-0.0587x]%29%2F263+%29]). For the second integral (and third and fourth), [click here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral[+%28264-Exp[-0.0587x]%29%2F263+*+Exp[-%28r%2Bd%29x]+%2C+{x%2CR%2CS}]). The first one is by far the most complicated. You'll have to look into the `hypergeom` function and how to get 2F1(*a*,*b*,*c*,*x*) out of it.

Comment: @Vokram: Note that the first integral is also not definite (e.g., you still have to evaluate it at both `S` and `0` and subtract). My suspicion is that, although complicated, it will be orders of magnitude faster. Especially the second equation of course becomes easy to evaluate.

Comment: Rody, that is awesome!! With an analytic form it would be much easier for me to see what the reasonable range is for these parameter. Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 2):

Internally MATLAB will evaluate the function `fun` for necessary values of `x`, which is more than one and `x` is a vector. `a` and `b` are only used to describe the limits of integration. From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/quadl.html)

> fun is a function handle. It accepts a vector x and returns a vector y, the function fun evaluated at each element of x. Limits a and b must be finite.

Hence, you must use `.^` to operate on individual elements of vector `x`.

Comment: Thank you angainor, but can you elaborate a bit more on what the "necessary values of x" are? Are they the points where `quadl` attempts to calculate the function numerically and see how close the answer is to zero?

Comment: @Vokram Those are defined for the *adaptive [Lobatto quadrature*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LobattoQuadrature.html) used in `quadl` (see documentation). The method is based on evaluating the function in specific points in order to integrate it numerically.

Comment: @Vokram The `x` values will be from `[a, b]` range, but there will be many of them.